# Typescript conditional mapped types loses return type information

Tags: typescript, conditional-types, mapped-types

I'm trying to wrap my head around conditional mapped types.  If I have a type defined as:

```
type StringyProps<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends string ? K : never }[keyof T];
```

What's the `[keyof T]` construct at the end doing?  How can find documentation about what you can do with that?

Also, I've written a function:

```
function getString<T>(thing: T, prop: StringyProps<T>): string {
  return thing[prop] as string;
}
```

If I have an interface as follows:

```
interface Something {
  name: string,
  id: string,
  age: number,
  weight: number
}
```

I get the following compile time errors:

```
console.log(getString(pippy, "name")); // ok
console.log(getString(pippy, "age")); // age is not assignable to parameter of type "name" | "id"
```

That's pretty awesome, but my function won't compile because it may be a mistake to assign the StringyProp's value to a string.  If I change the return to `return thing[prop] as unknown as string` it returns the correct value.

How can I construct this so that I don't have to assert unknown and re-assert string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript can't follow the fact that `StringyProps<T>` represenst only `string` prfoperty keys. The best solution is to use a type assertion:

```
function getString<T>(thing: T, prop: StringyProps<T>): string {
  return thing[prop] as unknown as string;
}
```

You can also change the types around a little bit, but intelisense will not suggest keys anymore so I don't really think it's worth it, call site experience is more important:

```
function getString<K extends PropertyKey>(thing: Record<K, string>, prop: K): string {
  return thing[prop]; // ok no assertion
}

console.log(getString(pippy, "name")); // ok
console.log(getString(pippy, "age")); //err
```

Comment: That makes sense.  That would surely be a lot to ask of the compiler to keep track of.  I'm actually amazed at how much I was able to do with this!  I agree with you that I care more about call site experience.  If I was super worried about it, I could accept a selector of type `(model: t) => string`.  I'm just super new to typescript and diving into things like this helps me get my bearings.  Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @D.Patrick You are welcomed, don't forget to upvote and mark as answered :)